# Binding a state to another div after altered (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, uikit, vue-component

I'm using a slider from UIKit, which has no documentation on how to use their events. The slider's data is fed by an API with Vuex. I am using a `v-for` to iterate through the data and show that many slides. I also have another section in the site that needs to be updated depending on the slide with `class="uk-active"` (generated by UIKit). I bound an ID to the slides to make them unique. What am looking to do here is:

- If slide has class `uk-active`, save its ID on a variable.
- Once I have the ID captured according to the `uk-active` class, show the piece of state value called `"number"` that corresponds to that ID

*template excerpt*:

```html
<div class="cts-split-grid cts-alt-header">
  <div>POD number here</div>
</div>

<ul id="podSlideshow" class="uk-slider-items cts-h">
  <li v-for="pods in allPods" :key="pods.id" :id="pods.id">
  ... the data that gets looped ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to fetch the ID by `className` in the `mounted` lifecycle hook, but the `classList` was not recognized. The class changes on-off according to the slider changing, so perhaps its effect is in a different lifecycle. Either way, I couldn't figure it out.

I'm ok with a Vue solutions using directives or a Javascript solution as well.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLs18rez/1/)

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, your fiddle seems to already be doing what you're seeking (i.e., displaying `pods.number` corresponding to the active slider item). What am I missing?

Comment: @tony19 it does it within the v-for because the data is within scope. I need to access the populate the pods.number where it says "number here" which is outside of the v-for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vue's [string interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text) and [event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) instead of DOM manipulation.

The UIKit slider's `beforeitemshow` event has an event-detail that indicates the item about to be shown, which also includes the item's index in the list. You could attach a `beforeitemshow`-handler to the `uk-slider` **(1)** that uses the item index to look up the corresponding ID in `allPods` **(2)**.

To have the ID shown in the header `div`, add a data property to be interpolated in the template **(3)**, initialize it in the [`mounted` hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) **(4)** (or in a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `allPods`), and set that property when the item ID is determined in the event handler previously mentioned **(5)**.

```html
<div class="cts-split-grid cts-alt-header">
  <div>POD {{currentPodId}}</div> <!-- (3a) -->
</div>
<div @beforeitemshow="onItemShown" uk-slider> <!-- (1a) -->
...
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentPodId: '', /* (3b) */
    allPods: [{ id: 'pod1' }, /* ... */]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.currentPodId = this.allPods[0].id /* (4) */
  },
  methods: {
    onItemShown(e) { /* (1b) */
      const shownItem = e.detail[0]
      this.currentPodId /* (5) */ = this.allPods[shownItem.index].id /* (2) */
    },
  }
```

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aet4f3hv/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Works exactly as I envisioned it. And I can see the logic in how you did it. Which will help me on other stuff I got going on. I do have a TypeError tho, but as long as it works, I'm not too worried. 
`Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"`

Comment: That likely means `allPods` is not yet populated by your Vuex store. In that case, use a watcher instead, so that the setting is not dependent on lifecycle hooks.